# Finding common components using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to find all the orders that have components in common and in addition the list of components in common:

Component Class:

```
public class Component
{
    public Component(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Order Class:

```
internal class Order
{
    public Order(string name,List<Component> components)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Components = components;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public List<Component>Components { get; private set; }
}
```

For example:

```
var component1 = new Component("B1");
var component2 = new Component("B2");
var component3 = new Component("B3");
var component4 = new Component("B4");

var order1 = new Order("M1", new List<Component> { component2 });
var order2 = new Order("M2", new List<Component> { component1, component2, component3, component4 });
var order3 = new Order("M3", new List<Component> { component1, component2 });

var dependents = from cmp1 in order1.Components
                 join cmp2 in order2.Components
                 on cmp1.Name equals cmp2.Name
                 select new
                 {
                     order1Name = order1.Name,
                     order2Name = order2.Name,
                     ComponentName = cmp1.Name
                 };

var result = dependents.ToList();
```

The result is showing the correct information, the common component between `order1` and `order2` which is `component2` ("B2").

How can I make it more general using orders list:

```
    var orders = new List<Order> { order1, order2, order3 };
```

I would like to get as result, for each 2 orders a list of components in common instead of doing it for each possible pair.
I presume this is something like:

```
var allDependents = 
runs.ForEach(order=>order.Components)                
....
from cmp1 in order1.Components
join cmp2 in order2.Components
on cmp1.Name equals cmp2.Name
select new
{
    order1Name = order1.Name,
    order2Name = order2.Name,
    ComponentName = cmp1.Name
};
```

Additional Info:

As per the following picture, we can see for each 2 orders, a list of components

[image]

Comment: orders.SelectMany(col=>col.Components, (o,co)=> new {O=o.Name, C=co.Name})
 .GroupBy(key=>key.C)
 .Select(kv=> new {K=kv.Key, L=string.Join(",",kv.Select(kvv=>kvv.O))})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming all the names are unique you could do this.

```
var results = from o1 in orders
              from c1 in o1.Components
              from o2 in orders.SkipWhile(o => o.Name != o1.Name)
              from c2 in o2.Components
              where o1.Name != o2.Name && c1.Name == c2.Name
              select new 
              {  
                  Order1 = o1.Name,   
                  Order2 = o2.Name,   
                  Component = c1.Name   
              };

foreach(var r in results) Console.WriteLine(r);
```

It produces this output

> { Order1 = M1, Order2 = M2, Component = B2 }
>
> { Order1 = M1, Order2 = M3, Component = B2 }
>
> { Order1 = M2, Order2 = M3, Component = B1 }
>
> { Order1 = M2, Order2 = M3, Component = B2 }

Comment: Great, If I need to have as result:
{ Order1 = M1, Order2 = M2, Component = B2 }
{ Order1 = M1, Order2 = M3, Component = B2 }
{ Order1 = M2, Order2 = M3, Component = B1,B2 }, I need a new LINQ and perform a group by, right?

Comment: Cartesian product. O(N^2). But of course (typical for LINQ tag) nobody cares.

Answer (score 4):

One possible efficient way is to use semi-join with additional criteria like this:

```
var orders = new List<Order> { order1, order2, order3 };
var orderComponents = from order in orders
         from component in order.Components
         select new { order, component };
var dependents =
    from e1 in orderComponents
    join e2 in orderComponents on e1.component.Name equals e2.component.Name
    where e2.order != e1.order && e2.order.Name.CompareTo(e1.order.Name) > 0
    select new
    {
        order1Name = e1.order.Name,
        order2Name = e2.order.Name,
        ComponentName = e1.component.Name
    };
```

The only detail to be mentioned is the criteria `e2.order != e1.order && e2.order.Name.CompareTo(e1.order.Name) > 0`. The first condition excludes the order from the left side while the second excludes duplicates like { M2, M1 }.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more experienced with the Fluent Linq syntax, in which you can do what you want:

```
var orders = new[] { order1, order2, order3 };

var dependents = orders.SelectMany(order =>
        orders
        .Where(other => other.Name != order.Name)
        .SelectMany(other => other.Components.Intersect(order.Components)
        .Select(c => new { order, other, component = c }))
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: That will produce duplicates.  Basically it will match the B2 in M1 as the "order" with M2 as the "other" then it will match them where M1 is the "other" and M2 is the "order".

Comment: True. Depending on the size of the queries and if items are identified by strings, It's easy to add a .Distinct()

Comment: `Distinct` will not work because the duplicates are not exact duplicates.  Basically one would be <M1, M2, B2> and the other would be <M2, M1, B2>.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookup (warning: untested code):

```
var lookup = orders
    .SelectMany(ord => ord.Components.Select(cmp => new { Order = ord, Component = cmp)
    .ToLookup(obj => obj.Component /* or obj.Component.Name, if you prefer */)
    .Where(lkp => lkp.Count() > 1);

foreach(var orders in lookup)
{
    // orders.Key is the component, orders is an Enumeration of orders containing that component.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `IEquatable<T>` on `Component` and on `Order`, and also override `object.Equals()` (as good practice), you can do something like:

```
var ordersA = new List<Order> { order1, order2, order3 };
var ordersB = new List<Order> { order2, order3 };

bool equal = ordersA.Equals(ordersB);
```

The 'equals' implementation on `Component` will also allow you to get common components by using set intersections like:

```
var compA = new List<Component> { c1, c2, c3};
var compB = new List<Component> { c2, c3};

var commonComponents = compA.Intersect(compB);
```

You could even use `Intersect` on lists of `Order`.